# Get image from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm building a blog where an authenticated user should be able to include an image in a post. I have read all documentation provided by firebase but the only solution I find is to provide the name of the image stored.

The problem is that I don't know what the name of the image will be so I'm looking for a solution where I could use e.target or something to pick the correct image.

Right now, I'm only able to fetch an image if I provide the name of the image in the storage.

```
const uploadImage = () => {
    if (image == null) return;
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image.name}`);
    uploadBytes(imageRef, image).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
        setImageUrls((prev) => [...prev, url]);
      });
    });
  };
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      const storage = getStorage();
      const img = ref(storage, `images/${image.name}`); // not working
      await getDownloadURL(img).then((x) => {
        setUrl(x);
      });
    };
    if (url === undefined) {
      fetch();
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: "*I'm only able to fetch an image if I provide the name of the image in the storage"* - this is always going to be true.  If you don't know the name of the object you can't do anything with it.  It's unclear to me how you think it might work differently.  It sounds like you're going to have to store that string somewhere to use it later?